# Query returns 1 row but throws error for more

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a very weird problem.

I have the following query :

```
dbms_output.put_line('Prefix : ' || prefix || 'Vendor ID :' || vendor_id);

select  r.rate 
into rate
from rates r
where r.quality = 0
and r.vendor_id = vendor_id
and r.prefix = prefix
and r.direction = 'OUT'
and r.calendar_value = 0
and (sysdate-(1/24/60) >= r.effective_date_from 
and sysdate-(1/24/60)  < nvl(r.effective_date_to, sysdate));
```

Now rate,vendor_id and prefix are 3 variables, all 3 are numbers.
This query is in a stored procedure, and right before this query I output both vars, which prints `Prefix : 5 Vendor ID : 361`

And this query falls on `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows`

The thing is, if I copy/paste this query to a separate SQL query outside the procedure with `5` and `361`, I get 1 row.

Does anyone know why this could happen? I'm on Oracle 11g

Comment: Are you sure you didn't get the error because rates contains duplicates for some values of effective_date_from / effective_date_to? This might cause your query to fail, but only when run at certain times.

Comment: You could do a count first and see how many rows there are.

Comment: Why should it affected the query? in this case effected_date_to is null so sysdate is taken, but I don't see how it matters since it's not the only filter term.

Comment: @Devolus Doing `count(*)` throws `invalid number` for some reason.

Comment: @eric.itzhak See my answer for an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have no idea what was the problem.

But changing the variables `prefix` and `vendor_id` to different names fixed the problem.

Maybe it's somehow related to the scope of the variables of perhaps different procedures of the same user using the same name or something, not sure.

Comment: The problem is your where clause:
and r.vendor_id = vendor_id
This is true for all rows (at least those where vendor_id is not null), since you compare the column value to itself. The most sensible thing to do is to use a naming convention for your procedure parameters, e.g. p_vendor_id for param vendor_id and l_vendor_id for local variable vendor_id.

Comment: Thanks, will note for future code, never had this problem before.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Yes, yes, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet you have duplicates in your input. Consider the following data:

```
create table rates (pk number not null primary key, rate number, 
  quality number, vendor_id number, prefix number,
  direction varchar2(30), calendar_value number, 
  effective_date_from date, effective_date_to date);      

insert into rates values(1, 2, 0, 361, 5, 'OUT', 0, 
  to_date('2013-04-25 13:40:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'), 
  to_date('2013-04-25 13:45:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'));

insert into rates values(2, 3, 0, 361, 5, 'OUT', 0, 
  to_date('2013-04-25 13:45:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'), 
  to_date('2013-04-25 13:46:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'));

insert into rates values(3, 4, 0, 361, 5, 'OUT', 0, 
  to_date('2013-04-25 13:45:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'), 
  null);
```

(note the overlap between rows 2 and 3).

Given this data, your query will return

- 1 row if run between 13:45:00 and 13:45:30
- 2 rows if run between 13:45:30 and 13:46:00
- 1 row afterwards

Comment: This does makes sense on a general term, but I know in fact that the above table has only 1 row for the prefix `5` and vendor_id `361`.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it failed when run with prefix = 5 and vendor_id = 361, then? Are you also 100% sure it didn't contain different data at the time you encountered this error?

Comment: Well that's according to Sql Developers error line number, I tried removing this query and the error changed to something in the next queries, so that does seem like it's this query.

Comment: However, if I manually insert those values in the procedure it runs, and a sec before when I output it it shows the same values.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a row with blank spaces in the table, for ex. The blank space is not null, it is a character. But you may not see it in output when running your query outside the procedure. 
The SELECT INTO or implicit cursor will always raise an Exception if there are more then one row exists or no rows exist. Use explicit cursor or handle the exception. In your case the exception is Too_Many_Rows.

Comment: Thank you. The explicit cursor and/or exception handlers will really solve the problem. You may get more then one row or no row in your table that satisfy your where condition in the future. Then your program will fail. This was my main point.